# Fullcalendar Scheduler, When creating new event does not update the calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I'm creating a reservation for projector and upon development, I'm stucked here where every time I dragged new events, it does not create new event in the calendar view. I tried alerting the values and I retrieved it correctly, only the calendar is not updating. Fullcalendar + Scheduler has a limited resources over the internet so I tried asking here.  Anybody knows what's missing or what should be done?[image]

```
select: function(info) 
   {

       this.title = prompt('Event Title:');

       if (this.title) {

           this.eventData = {
               title: this.title,
               start: info.start,
               end: info.end,
               resourceId: info.resource.id // Example  of resource ID
           };

             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', this.eventData, true); // stick? = true
       }
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
       alert('selected ' + info.start + ' to ' + info.endStr + 'wew ' + info.resource.id);
   },
```

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar are you using? Some of your syntax is as per v4 and some is as per V3...but they are very different, you can't mix the two. And have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Version 4.1 sir. So far, there are no console errors, it's just that, it does not update the events in the calendar view

Comment: Thanks sir, I tend to forget that V3 and V4 syntaxes are different, Just migrated to pure v4 codes and add .addEvent method and is now problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
calendar.addEvent({
                        id: NewEventID, resourceId: info.resource.id, start: info.startStr, end: info.endStr, title: Title2
                    });
```

Here's what I forgot to do, then refetch the events using   calendar.refetchEvents();. Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

Just migrated to pure V4, remove V3 syntaxes and included the .addEvent function. Problem solved!

Comment: It might be useful to others reading this who have a similar problem to show exactly what you changed. That would make the answer worth an upvote...